# Pivoting Data Via Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a collection of maps that get returned from a db with the following layout of data

```
[{:date "2012-6-6" :region "US" :status 1}
 {:date "2012-6-10" :region "UK" :status 2}
 {:date "2012-6-10" :region "US" :status 1}
 {:date "2012-6-11" :region "UK" :status 3}]
```

I'd like to pivot/transpose the data such that I get

```
[{:date "2012-6-6" :US 1 :UK 0}
 {:date "2012-6-10" :US 1 :UK 2}
 {:date "2012-6-11" :US 0 :UK 3}]
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you having trouble with something, or do you just want us to do your work for you?

Comment: Please post some code; it is a helpful thing to do. One of the nice things about Clojure (and some other languages like Python) is you can play around a lot and develop and understanding of what you're trying to do at the command line. I've got enough posts in here after doing that, and then people more experienced see I've been hammering away at the problem.

Comment: Well i guess the question would be is there an easy way to do this? Esp. because i also need aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is one way you could solve this *specifically as the problem is described*--as in, without any generality:

```
(def data
  [{:date "2012-6-6" :region "US" :status 1}
   {:date "2012-6-10" :region "UK" :status 2}
   {:date "2012-6-10" :region "US" :status 1}
   {:date "2012-6-11" :region "UK" :status 3}]

=> (map (fn [[date data-points]]
          (apply assoc {:date date}
                 (mapcat (juxt (comp keyword :region)
                               :status)
                         data-points)))
        (group-by :date
                  data)))
=> ({:US 1, :date "2012-6-6"}
    {:US 1, :UK 2, :date "2012-6-10"}
    {:UK 3, :date "2012-6-11"})
```

It works by grouping the data by date, then mapping a function down that (I'll talk about the function in a sec). `group-by` groups elements in a sequence by calling some function on them and grouping the ones that have equal return values for that function. It makes a hash map, where each unique return values is a key, and each value in the map is a sequence of the elements in the original sequence that returned that value. For example, here's what your data will looked like grouped by date:

```
{"2012-6-6" [{:status 1
              :date "2012-6-6"
              :region "US"}]
 "2012-6-10" [{:status 2
               :date "2012-6-10"
               :region "UK"}
              {:status 1
               :date "2012-6-10"
               :region "US"}]
 "2012-6-11" [{:status 3
               :date "2012-6-11"
               :region "UK"}]}
```

So that's how group-by works. Now the function that is mapped down this grouped data will bind `date` to the first element of each sequence, and `data-points` to the second element of each sequence. We will `(apply assoc {:date date} ...)` to a "restructuring" of the data points, where what was the value at `:region` is now a keyword for what was the value at `:status`. The "restructuring" happens by [`mapcat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mapcat)-ing down `data-points` with a function that is the [`juxt`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/juxt) of calling `(comp keyword :region)` and `:status` on each data point.

To hopefully elucidate what this `juxt`-ed function is doing, I've given what the equivalent would look like if it were written out:

```
(defn above-juxted-fn
  [data-point]
  [(keyword (:region data-point))
   (:status data-point)])
```

Now, actually this is not a complete solution, because you seem to want to include all possible regions as keywords, and if there is no data for that region and date, then for the value to be zero. However, with what the above solution returns, whenever you did `(get region-key-here)` for any data-point, you could instead do `(get region-key-here 0)`, so that the default would be zero if the lookup failed to find the given region key.

Another thing: if you are processing a lot of data, I'm not convinced this would be a particularly fast way of doing things (maybe others would have more accurate and detailed advice here). I wrote it aiming for simplicity and minimality.

Also, as I said above, it has no generality. As for the generality, we can change that by molding it into a function that takes three arguments: 1) a sequence of maps 2) a grouping key and 3) a sequence of "new-key-at" "new-val-at" pairs, which I call the restructuring specs (for example, in the above, this would be `[:region :status]`). Here goes:

```
(defn group-and-restructure
  [data grouping-key & restructuring-specs]
  (let [grouped-data (group-by grouping-key
                               data)
        restructuring-fn (apply juxt
                                (mapcat (fn [[k1 k2]]
                                          [(comp keyword k1)
                                           k2])
                                        restructuring-specs))]
    (map (fn [[grouping-k-value
               data-points]]
           (apply assoc {grouping-key grouping-k-value}
                  (mapcat restructuring-fn
                          data-points)))
         grouped-data)))

=> (group-and-restructure
     [{:date "2012-6-6" :region "US" :status 1}
      {:date "2012-6-10" :region "UK" :status 2}
      {:date "2012-6-10" :region "US" :status 1}
      {:date "2012-6-11" :region "UK" :status 3}]
     :date
     [:region :status])
=> ({:US 1, :date "2012-6-6"}
    {:US 1, :UK 2, :date "2012-6-10"}
    {:UK 3, :date "2012-6-11"})
```

This works very similarly to the specific solution above. The main difference is that the restructuring specs are converted into a function that, when `mapcat`-ted down `data-points`, will return a new sequence of key/val pairs to be `assoc`-ed into the new return data. The best part is that this function allows you to flexibly restructure your data. For example, you could group by `:region` and restructure by `[:date :status]`, like so:

```
=> (group-and-restructure
     [{:date "2012-6-6" :region "US" :status 1}
      {:date "2012-6-10" :region "UK" :status 2}
      {:date "2012-6-10" :region "US" :status 1}
      {:date "2012-6-11" :region "UK" :status 3}]
     :region
     [:date :status])
=> ({:2012-6-10 1, :2012-6-6 1, :region "US"}
    {:2012-6-11 3, :2012-6-10 2, :region "UK"})
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't handle the case where you need zero for missing regions.

```
(->> (group-by :date DB-DATA)
     (map (fn [[_ coll]]
            (apply merge (map (fn [{:keys [status date region]}]
                                {:date date (keyword region) status})
                              coll))))
     vec)
=> [{:date "2012-6-6", :US 1} {:US 1, :date "2012-6-10", :UK 2} {:date "2012-6-11", :UK 3}]
```